# Splitting rows to bin by datetimes / recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, reporting-services, common-table-expression

I need to bin data per day utilizing an SQL query so that I can get it in bins to use in SSRS for a report, ie, 12am-12am. I have rows that have time intervals that extend through 12am, possibly through multiple days. I would like to split the rows that extend one or more 12am time boundaries into multiple rows, so that I can then group by day to do some summations. For example here are 3 rows:

```
StateName   StartDT LastDT  IntervalMin FullName
RUN_PARTS   2017-01-24 23:09:29.46  2017-01-25 02:19:32.29  190.04 SPECTOR4            
IDLE    2017-01-25 02:19:32.29  2017-01-25 03:11:32.91  52.01   SPECTOR4            
MAINTENANCE_GENERAL 2017-01-25 03:11:32.91  2017-01-25 18:31:44.26  920.18  SPECTOR4
```

I would like to get this data (1st row split at 12am, IntervalMin updated for new start, stop times):

```
StateName   StartDT LastDT  IntervalMin FullName
RUN_PARTS   2017-01-24 23:09:29.46  2017-01-25 00:00:00.00  50.30 SPECTOR4 
RUN_PARTS   2017-01-25 00:00:00.00  2017-01-25 02:19:32.29  139.28 SPECTOR4 
IDLE    2017-01-25 02:19:32.29  2017-01-25 03:11:32.91  52.01   SPECTOR4            
MAINTENANCE_GENERAL 2017-01-25 03:11:32.91  2017-01-25 18:31:44.26  920.18  SPECTOR4
```

Does this make sense? I would need to handle the case when the first row extends through multiple 12am boundaries (ie, time interval more than 24 hours).

After reading a bunch of stuff it looks like recursive CTE should be able to do this, however, I cannot wrap my head around this.

I am referring specifically to this example as it is close to what I want to do:

### [Split row based on start end date SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476272/split-row-based-on-start-end-date-sql-server)

For more clarity here is what generates the data I am trying to split:

```
declare @STARTDT as datetime2
declare @STOPDT as datetime2
declare @CNAME as VARCHAR(70) 

SET @STARTDT = DATEADD(d, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
SET @STOPDT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SET @CNAME = 'Spector4'

SELECT
CoatingChamberStates.Name
,CCSL.StartDT as StartDT
,CCSL.LastDT as LastDT
,CCSL.IntervalMin
,CoatingChambers.FullName

FROM CoatingChamberStateLogs as CCSL
INNER JOIN CoatingChamberStates on CCSL.CoatingChamberStatesID = CoatingChamberStates.CoatingChamberStatesID
INNER JOIN CoatingChambers on CCSL.CoatingChambersID = CoatingChambers.CoatingChambersID

where CCSL.StartDT >= @STARTDT
and CCSL.LastDT <= @STOPDT
and CoatingChambers.FullName = @CNAME
```

Or, if you have a better idea about how to approach this, I would appreciate it. My goal is to evaluate and find limitation on SSRS, but I think that this recursive CTE could solve this current limitation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. This would be easier if you can generate a dates table with all possible dates. You can then `join` it with the existing table to split the rows based on a `case` expression logic if they span multiple days.

```
with dates(dt) as (select '2017-01-24' union all select '2017-01-25' union all select '2017-01-26' union all select '2017-01-27')
--This just uses the dates from the example in question
/*To generate dates for a given timeframe (for example all dates in 2017), use
with dates(dt) as (select '2017-01-01' 
                   union all
                   select dateadd(day,1,dt) from dates where dt < '2017-12-31')
*/
select t.statename 
,case when t.startdt>=d.dt then t.startdt else d.dt end as startdt
,case when datediff(day,lastdt,dt)=0 then t.lastdt else dateadd(day,1,d.dt) end as lastdt 
,datediff(millisecond
          ,case when t.startdt>=d.dt then t.startdt else d.dt end
          ,case when datediff(day,lastdt,dt)=0 then t.lastdt else dateadd(day,1,d.dt) end)/60000.0 
 as split_diff
,t.fullname
from t
join dates d on d.dt >= cast(t.startdt as date) and d.dt<=cast(t.lastdt as date)
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/MZOV62442)